# Create a PC Scheduled Task to date check 2 files on SharePoint and if newer than local copies, copy new ones down to PC

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to copy files from sharepoint to local C: drive, this will be running as a scheduled task. I need only copy if the Sharepoint files are NEWER than the local files.

I seem to have the leads on the copy, but i dont find how to query the last modify date of a sharepoint file.

thanks